# Multiple small spritesheets or one giant spritesheet for performance? --- (java game development)

Tags: java, performance, sprite-sheet

So I know that using a spritesheet is much better than loading singular images, but what would be the best implementation of a spritesheet?

Using many spritesheets, (for example in a game, one for each character, etc), or putting all your images into one MEGA spritesheet that could be say 10,000 x 10,000 in size.

Which of the two would give better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using spritesheets for any animations and static sprites that are likely to appear in the same section/level of a the game is usually the best way to go. Having one giant spritesheet *might* yield slightly better performance, but you hit the law of diminishing returns fairly quickly, and it may make things more memory intensive.

Spritesheets tend to make things more efficient in a couple of ways:

- They reduce the significant overhead of reading image data from disk (or via network requests).
  Sprites are almost always loaded before a game starts, since trying to get all that data on the fly would be noticeably awful. So having sprite sheets will likely cut down on your load time and having one giant spritesheet may speed this up, but also means that you will have to load every sprite in the game--even if your only going to use a few. This will have a bigger memory footprint, but it's probably not enough to make much of a difference.
- They speed up painting/animation by allowing simple translation of images that are already in memory, rather than copying bunch of data around.
  This is probably the more significant performance benefit provided by spritesheets.  Often, these kinds of transformations are hardware accelerated (though that really depends on the system architecture), but it's far more performant than copying image data around, even without hardware acceleration. A giant spritesheet might not yield much gain, here, since you only need the frames that exist in the animation to be in the sprite.

Since there is only the potential of a small performance gain in having a giant spritesheet vs. a few well organized ones, I would recommend the easiest implementation. If one giant spritesheet is difficult to work with in your system, you're probably going to end up doing awkward things, in code, to manage it, which will end up nuking any performance gains pretty quickly.  But if you have a system that deals with it very well, and it's a matter of flipping some kinds of configurations, it might be worth doing.

Comment: Also be aware that hardware accelerated graphics systems can have lower than usual limits to the size of data that it works with.  If a single image gets too big (10,000x10,000 seems reasonable, though), graphics acceleration can be compromised. Most systems have pretty good graphics processing capabilities now, though...just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

**What is your target platform?**

Most game development frameworks use OpenGL for rendering (e.g. libgdx, andengine,...) - this increases performance but comes with restrictions: **Don't create sprite sheets bigger than 2048x2048 for mobile**. I would recommend staying below 4096x4096 for all devices. Desktops can handle bigger textures but you might get problems with shader precisions.

**Performance**

Changing textures and setting parameters for OpenGL costs time.

Using single sprites looks like this (pseudo code)

```
foreach(sprite in sprites)
{
    opengl.setTexture(sprite.texture)
    opengl.setTextureCoordinates(sprite.sourceRect)
    opengl.setTargetCoordinates(sprite.screenPosition)
    opengl.draw()
}
```

So you have about 4 calls for each of your sprite. 100 sprites => 400 OpenGL calls. **This is bad!**

After the `draw()` it might be required to wait until the next texture can be set.

To optimize the number of draw calls your game engine batches the painting of the sprites.

The game engine can draw all sprites that are on one sprite sheet with 3 draw calls:

```
foreach(sprite in sprites)
{
    textureCoordinates.append(sprite.sourceRect)
    screenPositions.append(sprite.screenPosition)
}

opengl.setTexture(sheet.texture)
opengl.setTextureCoordinates(textureCoordinates)
opengl.setTargetCoordinates(screenPositions)
opengl.draw()
```

1 Sprite sheet, 4 OpenGL calls. **This is good!**

This is too theoretical? Here's a funny video about [optimizing game performance](https://www.codeandweb.com/what-is-a-sprite-sheet-performance).

You see: Using sprite sheets is important.

The painting start with objects in the background, working to the foreground. This is required to ensure that the transparency is handled correctly for overlapping objects.

This works perfectly as long as you can put all sprites in 1 sheet.
If you have many animations the restrictions with mobile (mentioned above) might not allow you to place everything in 1 sheet.

So distributing your sprites across multiple sprite sheets requires a bit more thinking:

Group your sprites, objects and ui elements in layers - depending on how they overlap:

- Place everything that is **clearly behind** other sprites in 1 sheet. E.g. background graphics.
- Place everything that is **clearly before** other sprites in 1 sheet. E.g. UI elements, HUD, score
- Place everything that might appear **before or behind** some other object in one sheet.

The first 2 are quite obvious - the latter maybe not.

As explained above: The game engine starts with the background, working to the front. It first draws your background in 1 batch. Fine.

Then it comes to the characters, enemies, bullets, game objects whatever.
All on one sheet: No problem. Multiple sheets: Textures might have to be switched - forcing additional draw calls: Overlapping sprites in your game (background to foreground):

```
Sheet A: Sprites: a1,a2
Sheet B: Sprites b1

a1,a2,b1 => 2 batches: A,B 
a1,b1,a2 => 3 batches: A,B,A
```

So: If you can't fit all game objects, enemies and character in 1 sheet make sure to define a clear z-order for them:

- Enemies in background
- Character in the middle
- Bullets in the front
- Game objects in the front

Group as much as possible in one sheet - but don't distribute one set on different sheets. Make sure that your game also sticks to the order.

**Packing sprites**

Transparency does not seem to be nothing on a sprite. It's just transparent, right? No!

Transparency is expensive. It wastes memory. It also costs performance - because all the transparent pixels have to be read & processed by OpenGL.

Use a software that gets the maximum out of your sprite sheets. Game engines support trimmed sprites, that is: Sprites without additional transparency - while keeping the animations stable and jitter-free.

Take a look at this [sprite sheet maker](https://www.codeandweb.com/sprite-sheet-maker) - it takes care of packing your sheets, removing additional transparency and everything you need.